# How to add Address, Zip Code when Creating customer in Stripe?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

Dear Stack overflow users,

I'm trying to create a customer through the Stripe API in PHP. But I'm not sure how I can add the optional child arguments; name, address_city, address_country, address_zip etc.

I added them as metadata but then they don't show up under the customer's card.

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(

                array(
                'email'=>$email,
                'source'=>$token,
                 'metadata'=>array(
                  'full_name'=>$fullname,
                  'address'=>$address,
                  'zip_code'=>$zip_code,
                  'city'=>$city,
                  'country'=>$country,
                  'email'=>$email
                  ),
                  'plan'=>$plan

                   )
                  );
```

I would also like to ask; Do you recommend adding these "optional" fields. Is it Higher/lower risk that a card gets declined like this? Does it look better for Stripe when we include these fields?

Please let me know :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to save only customer card and email and then retrieve customer ID from stripe and save it in your own database along with other details like address, city and country etc.

Create new customer in stripe

```
$customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
   "card" => $_POST['CARD'],
   "email" => $_POST['EMAIL']
));
```

Use this customer key in creating subscriber and then insert into your database

```
$CUST_KEY = $customer->id;
```

Later you can use the customer key to add another subscriber and can map any customer detail on your database with your stripe account.

```
Stripe_Customer::retrieve("$CUST_KEY");
```

Comment: Thank you! My main concern and question was if It's better if I pass this info to Stripe? Will it make it more likely that a card gets approved/declined?

Comment: Stripe check card number and expiry month/year to approve or decline the payment. It doesn't have anything to do with other info so as I mentioned in my answer also, keep other data in your own database so you can easily update it easily without the need to connect to stripe server.